# how to send authenticated ajax call to web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api Application which has the following question.

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("Account/userName{userName}/password={password}/rememberMe/{rememberMe}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage LogIn(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "already logged in.");
        }

        var dbPerson = dbContext.Persons.Where(x => x.UserName.Equals(userName) && x.EncryptedPassword.Equals(password)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (dbPerson != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "logged in successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
```

I am calling from another MVC project. I Got the authentication but very next page where I am calling the ajax method

var uri = 'http://localhost:44297/api/XXXX';

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON(uri)
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.

          for (var i = 0; i < data.$values.length; i++)
          {      


             }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( "error" )});


});
```

I am getting GET http://localhost:44297/api/StudyFocus 401 (Unauthorized). how I can solve this issue. I know I need to pass some cookie/session value with this ajax call. but I don't know how. can anyone explain me with example.

My application relies on web Api project including authentication. I need to make web api application secure using form authentication. Any help is highly appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't authenticate web api by the use of cookies or session. You need access token to do that.

Follow this tutorial for the implementation http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read article one you shared. I dont want to register users with help of OAuth. How i can get the token only and used in my both MVC application and Web API Application for secure API Controller Action Method Calls.

Comment: You can implement  your own OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider to generate access token and create ClaimsIdentity for user's identity

Comment: Why not make authentication itself in an ordinary MVC manner (via forms), create authentication cookie and identity and then inside any ApiController ajax methods just to check this identity? If something is wrong with it - to take appropriate measure. No need to over-complicate things...

Comment: It's Web Api NOT MVC. LOL.